# Filter function with multiple criteria in same column in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I need to filter my data frame based on multiple condition on same column.
I do have query but I need more precise one. Here is my example.

```
 Admission method   Freq
11  7360
12  5172
13  3913
21  36599
22  7722
23  4
24  1011
28  679
31  1539
32  52
81  241
82  375
99  3


    IP <- IP_ID %>% filter(ADMISSION_METHOD == 21 |ADMISSION_METHOD == 22 | ADMISSION_METHOD == 23 | ADMISSION_METHOD == 24 | ADMISSION_METHOD == 28)

Another Method
    Adm_method <- c(21,22,23,24,28)
    t<- IP_ID %>% filter(ADMISSION_METHOD %in% Adm_method)
```

is there any short code to achieve this?

Thanks,
Prabha.

Comment: Are you sure that your JARs contain the native libraries? Sorry but you don't give enough information to allow us to help you. Moreover, the Java classes must match with the native libraries. If you mix Java classes and native libraries coming from different versions of JOGL, it won't work.

Comment: @gouessej Sorry could you please explain me about the native library GEPHI. I am using Eclipse IDE so I have native library. Is this you try to mention. I don't know how to resolve this library issue.

Comment: @gouessej I have checked my native library. It is there and it has org-jogamp-gluegen and org-jogamp-jogl

Comment: I don't know how Gephi packages JOGL. Please provide the full stack trace. Maybe GlueGen failed to load the native libraries for a reason I can't determine. Is gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar in your classpath if you're under Windows 64-bit?

Comment: Looks like you could use `%in%`. `IP_ID %>% filter(ADMISSION_METHOD %in% c(21, 22, 23, 24, 28))`

Comment: @bouncyball Thank you, I have tried this method too. Just edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this method:

```
 Adm_method <- c(21,22,23,24,28)
    t<- IP_ID %>% filter(ADMISSION_METHOD %in% Adm_method)
```